# Autolayout does not work correctly for groups of nodes. Where did I go wrong? Dargre-d3-es

Tags: reactjs, autolayout, nodes, diagram, dagre-d3

I use the library dagre-d3-es

Autolayout does not work correctly for groups of nodes. I made an autolayout for nodes, but when I use groups, the position for this group is not set correctly.
I put all the nodes in the graph, and the nodes that contain the parent group I used in the setParent method.

After calling the Laout function, the positions are given out, but not quite the correct positions are given to the groups of nodes. What could be the problem?

I tried to set the parent group through the setParent method; without this, the group of nodes is considered a node, and the autolayout behaves not like with a group of nodes in which there should be nodes but as with a separate node and allocates space for it. I need to put the nodes in a node group and make it look even. It will look exactly the same if the autolayout gives the correct position to this group of nodes. Screenshot example 1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEF7M.png)
Example screen 3 - what result is required[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqkoZ.png)

Comment: could you please share some snippets to your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.